# How to update the tab bar in .net Maui

Tags: c#, xaml, tabs, maui, app-shell

My application contains a global tab bar. The tabs in it can change their order, be removed or added and also change visually. Thus I'd like to update the tab bar at runtime. The user should not be moved to a different page, so the navigation stack should not change while updating. I tried to first clear the tab bar items and then add the correct ones back into it. But I encountered multiple problems with this approach, getting exceptions like:

`Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: MainPage`

I think the problem is that I clear the tabs, as then, for a moment, the shell is empty.

How can I have a dynamic tabbar in .net Maui?

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiTestApplication.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar x:Name="MainTabBar"/>

</Shell>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
public void UpdateTabs()
{
   MainTabBar.Items.Clear();
   // Create all tabs
   // Add all tabs to tabbar via: MainTabBar.Items.Add(TAB);
}
```

Comment: Did the exception throw when you add the tab or use shell navigation?

Comment: Yes, I think its thrown in non user code after the first item is added again.

Comment: I  made a demo and add more tabs in it. Please see my answer.

Comment: Very very very difficult task. Adding items to the TabBar is the easy part. You need to force the redraw. This is commonly solved by reconstruction of AppShell, or by calling a Navigation. And you cannot simply do navigation to the current position. It does not work like that. You need to actually go somewhere, and eventually go back with "..". The reconstruction way involves setting the CurrentItem, and you will lose any data you have on that page, including the whole nav stack. I am not aware of other solutions.

Comment: @H.A.H. Thanks for your answer. How would I navigate back to the page I was before the "reconstruction" of the tab bar. Because reconstructing it, always throws the user back to the main page anyway. (I tried to store the path from before and then use `GoToAsync` to navigate back, but that ran into the same error as described in the question)

Comment: No no. You cannot reconstruct and navigate back. You can either 1) Reconstruct and lose navigation stack and data , or 2) modify the tabbar at runtime, but navigate back and forth to force redraw. About your Error I will commend again.

Comment: Global routes cannot be left as the only page of the navigation stack by design. You cannot navigate to "DetailsPage", that is registered as global route, using "//DetailsPage". For this to work you need separate ShellItem. ShellItems are the topmost items in the Shell. (they on the other hand have sections and contents). If this "DetailsPage" is ShellItem, you can leave it as the only page on the stack. (//DetailsPage). If you show me every single place you are defining routing, and the exact navigation URL you are using, I can be very specific. But this is for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo to remove and add the tab again .

You could try the following code:

In ***AppShell.cs***

```
public void UpdateTabs()
{
    //MainTabBar.Items.Clear();

    //  I add these two lines, then it can add the tab in it
    //MainTabBar = new TabBar();
    //this.Items.Add(MainTabBar);

    MainTabBar.Items.Add(new ShellContent()
    {
        Title = "Home",
        ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MainPage()),
        Route = "mainpage",
    });

}
```

Hope it helps.

Create a new TabBar seems to empty the navigation stack. And you could just add and remove the item in it and not let it be empty.

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work to update the tab bar. In my case though, the navigation stack gets reset (throws the user back to the first page). Is there any way around this?

Comment: Currently I don't do any navigation after clearing and adding the tabs. But still the user is thrown back to the first page (MainPage). I guess this makes sense, as it is a new tab bar. I would however, like the user to be at the same position as before. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Then don't use ```MainTabBar.Items.Clear();```. You could add or remove item in MainTabBar but not let it be empty.

Comment: @Holunk I am not sure if it is the effect you want. I made a gif to show. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks! As long as the current Tab does not have to be changed, this will work. I will have to find another way to update the tab the user is currently on. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: What does "update the tab" mean?

Comment: I'm still working on this and am not sure if I need it. But as described in the question, the tabs will also change visually. I'm still unsure about whether or not the tab bar has to be redrawn. If yes, this would be a problem with this solution, as the current tab of the user does not get changed.